# Glide not loading real image and stuck with placeholder

Tags: android, android-glide

I have a pretty basic load image from server line code:

```
Glide.with(view.getContext()).load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.default_profile).into(view);
```

For some reason, I'm always stuck with the placeholder being displayed and never the real image!

I have made sure that a valid and working url is being passed. And, if I use the same code without the placeholder it works fine

```
Glide.with(view.getContext()).load(url).into(view);
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: For security reason, Android doesn't allow some of URL's. Think to add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in your manifest file. Detailed answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/1744705)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Try to add `.dontAnimate()` 
It caused by **TransitionDrawable** too and it seems so because after scroll there's no animation because it's cached.

The correct code is

```
Glide.with(view.getContext()).load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.default_profile).dontAnimate().into(view);
```

I hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: For some weird reason, this solved the issue. The transition is ugly though without the animation.

Comment: Place holder is not exist in Glide v4.0.0

Comment: Just as Glide's README.md says, CircleImageView/CircularImageView/RoundedImageView are known to have issues with TransitionDrawable (.crossFade() with .thumbnail() or .placeholder()) and animated GIFs, use a BitmapTransformation (.circleCrop() will be available in v4) or .dontAnimate() to fix the issue.

Answer (score 59):

Check if you have added Internet permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Glide does not fire exception if there is no Internet connectivity.

Comment: Indeed ! This solved the trouble for me. I think it would be more useful if glide raises an Exception when developper makes such a mistake.

Answer (score 10):

Add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in the application tag in manifest and check the internet permission is mentioned or not in the same manifest file:-

Answer (score 5):

Add this permission below to access resource endpoint/url

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

If your target endpoint/url only has **http** add this code below in your manifest.xml. Starting with Android 9 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default.

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Because of that, if you get resource from your unencrypted HTTP API don't forget to add

```
res/xml/network_security_config.xml
```

---

So the code will be like these

**network_security_config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">urweb.id</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        ...
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">111.222.333.444</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
    
        <activity>
        ...
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are tried following steps :

- INTERNET permission is already added both in Manifest and Programmatically
- usesCleartextTraffic : if already mentioned in Manifest
  Even though image is not loading in ImageView

Then try this :

- add this line **application** tag of Manifest

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

- add following code in the activity or fragment at top in which you are trying to perform the operation

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use ProgressBar as loading gif

```
Glide.with(context).
        load(url)
        .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return false;
            }
        })
        .crossFade(1000)
        .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 2):

If someone comes across this in the future you may need to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Unsure of the exact reason for this change, nonetheless my code didn't work without that permission, and now does with it.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a weird fix that worked for me.

The following always fails for me (12 trials) - I never see the real image:

```
Glide.with(context)
 .load(url)
 .asBitmap()
 .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(iconWidth, iconHeight) { ... }
```

The following always succeeds for me (12 trials) - I always see the real image:

```
Glide.with(context)
 .load(url)
 .asBitmap()
 .listener(new RequestListener() {
    public boolean onException(Exception e,Object o,Target t,boolean b)
               {return false;}
    public boolean onResourceReady(Object o,Object p,Target t,boolean b,boolean c)  
               {return false;}})
 .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(iconWidth, iconHeight) { ... }
```

As you can see, the only difference here is that I added a listener. Makes little sense, but these trials were done pretty carefully, so I'm going with it.

Comment: weird...this fixed it for me too...any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

None of the solutions above worked for me. The issue may be at the **placeholder** you're using. If the view you're using to load the image has a placeholder, it causes some issues. Removing that placeholder for some reason seems to fix it.

So, if the (Image)View you're trying to inflate has a placeholder, such as **android:src="@mipmap/placeholder"**, remove it.

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgGallery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/rugova1" />
```

like this

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgGallery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Seems strange but only thing I could guess is Your URL is valid as You already said. Your remote is getting downloaded even getting applied on your image view but your placeholder is somehow hiding it.
Glide has some bugs related to placeholder stuff.

My suggestion would be to try below:

```
Glide.with(view.getContext()).load(url).
placeholder(R.drawable.default_profile).fitCenter().into(view);
```

So the trick is placeholder is set via `setImageDrawable()` so the `ImageView` will just display it as usual, but you tell Glide to use the `fitCenter` explicitly which will fit the loaded image nicely within the `ImageView`'s laid out size via a Transformation and then set it via `setImageDrawable()`. Since the fitted image is a perfect fit, center will just draw the image covering the whole area of the view.

Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use transition or animation for Glide.It will solve your problem

Code :

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(horizontalHappyHourList.get(position).getImage())
//  .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade(400)) //Optional
    .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
    .error(R.drawable.no_image))
    .into(holder.imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

May help someone :)
  My issue was network security policy exception. The URL requested by Glide was blocked by android due to security policy.

Fixed by whitelisting desired domain. [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/5845024)

```
com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
There was 1 cause:
java.net.UnknownServiceException(CLEARTEXT communication to maps.googleapis.com not permitted by the network security policy)
 call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
```

The toughest thing is it was not shown in the normal log.

Answer (score 0):

Incase none of the above solves it, and you're setting the 'src' property on the ImageView, it won't work. I was mistakenly setting the 'src' on the ImageView in xml and taking that out solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check the url (link) as it may be a page link not an exact image address, try copying the link and paste it to the browser to see if it opens just image or a web page and if it opens a web page then no doubt that is the problem it is a page link and again not an image address.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31656516)