# android library glide is not working. only this form of url

Tags: android, imageview

I want to set this url photo "http://file.koreafilm.or.kr/thm/02/00/01/66/tn_DPF002814.JPG" in my app with glide library.

```
   Glide.with(context).
                load(movieImageArray.get(position)).error(R.drawable.gray_profile)
                .fallback(R.drawable.profile)
                .into(holder.imageMovieResult);
```

I wanna set this url photo into image view from Recycler view adapter. Other url is working in this code but only this form of url is not working. (I get url form other API. I can't change url form)
please help me!!!

Comment: Try this thread -https://stackoverflow.com/a/69148117

Answer (score 0):

For image url with http you have to add in you manifest file

<application
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
...

```
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow traffic from unsecure host, First of all create a file `network_security_config.xml` under `res/xml` directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">file.koreafilm.or.kr</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Where `file.koreafilm.or.kr` is the domain name you want to allow in insecure mode (not https)

Then in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
+   android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

The most important part here is this line `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"`

Answer (score 0):

For those URLs which are started by HTTP instead of HTTPS, you have to add the following statement in the application tag at the manifest file of your application.

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```