# Image from http url not show in glide

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with glide, when i load image from http it's not working, but if image is from https it work fine:

```
Glide.with(context).load("http://imageurl").into(holder.foto);
```

Comment: maybe duplicate [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384789/glide-not-loading-real-image-and-stuck-with-placeholder)

Answer (score 1):

For security reason, Android doesn't allow some of URL's. Think to add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in your manifest file.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ...>

    <activity>
    ...
    </activity>
</application>
```